# PHP Implode Prints "Array" instead of value

Tags: php

Below is the PHP code to retrieve data:

```
<?php
$sql = $myquery;
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$QueryArray = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $QueryArray[] = Array($row["Column1"], $row["Column2"], $row["Column3"]);

    }

} else {

}
?>
```

And on the HTML side:

```
<textarea style="width:100%; height:50%; resize:none; rows="5" cols="40">
<?php 
$output = implode("\n" , $QueryArray);
echo $output;
?>
</textarea>
```

However the below query prints:

```
Array
Array
Array
Array
..etc
```

Not sure where code is going wrong.

Comment: It's an array of arrays. Implode doesn't flatten it to be one dimensional.

Comment: how about implodeing:  `$QueryArray[] =$row["Column1"].' '.$row["Column2"].' '.$row["Column3"]);`

Comment: @Dagon Yes this is the solution

Comment: @Dagon Yes this is the solution

Comment: @Dagon i cant reference myself can i

Comment: @Fred -ii- sure why not?

Comment: people think im mad when i talk to myself on the street - little do the know ..

Comment: @Dagon They wouldn't know a genius if it trampled them under foot.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see `$QueryArray` is an array of arrays

```
$QueryArray[] = Array($row["Column1"], $row["Column2"], $row["Column3"]);
```

You can access the `$queryArray` elements (array), in a foreach loop. Than use implode to print what you want.

```
<textarea style="width:100%; height:50%; resize:none; rows="5" cols="40">
<?php
$output = '';
foreach($array in $QueryArray) {
    $output .= implode("\n" , $array);
}
echo $output;
?>
</textarea>
```

I hope it helps

Comment: You're right @Dagon. My solution is only a dirty fix. The better way is to create a mono dimensional array, concatenating resulting rows with a "\n", in that way: `$row["Column1"]. "\n". $row["Column2"]. "\n" .$row["Column3"]`

Comment: quick? this is a slower fix

Comment: @nessuno I prefer simple over complex, which is what Dagon provided, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

In your code $QueryArray is a array of array. if your field count are know, simply you can:

```
<?php 
$sql = $myquery;
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $QueryArray[] = $row["Column1"];
      $QueryArray[] = $row["Column2"];
      $QueryArray[] = $row["Column3"];
}
} else {}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but someone might need the answer.

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($QueryArray);
echo "</pre>";
```